# How to make my bot send a message that look like a box with different colors in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im trying to make a message that is kinda like a ballon message, and i cant find out how to make it work[i wanted it to be like this, could annyone help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAdGz.png) i am not worried about how to make it, i just want to make it work. Thanks for who tries out to make it.

I tried to make a ballon using pillow but i couldnt use it, because it said pillow wasnt available or something.

```
@bot.command(name='balloon')
```

async def create_balloon(ctx, color, *, text):
color = color.lower()  # Converta a cor para minúsculas para garantir consistência

````
# Verifique se a cor fornecida é válida
allowed_colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange', 'pink']
if color not in allowed_colors:
    await ctx.send("Cor inválida. Escolha entre: red, blue, green, yellow, purple, orange, pink.")
    return

# Crie a mensagem com o balão de conversa formatado
balloon_message = f"```{color}\n{text}\n```"
await ctx.send(balloon_message)
````

Comment: That is called an Embed. You can use `channel.send(embed=discord.Embed("Title"))` for example. The dropdown menu is part of an Interaction View.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what u want

```
options = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'] #add other colors in list

@client.tree.command(name="ballon", description="your description")
async def ballon(interaction: discord.Interaction, color: str):
    if color == 'red':
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Red Ballon", color=discord.Colour.red())
        embed.description = "you have chosen the red ballon!"

    elif color == 'blue':
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Blue Ballon", color=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.description = "you have chosen the blue ballon!"

    elif color == 'yellow':
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Yellow Ballon", color=discord.Colour.yellow())
        embed.description = "you have chosen the yellow ballon!"

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", color=discord.Colour.red())
        embed.description = "please select one of the following colors: 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'"

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```